# PHP website: Get Disqus comments and comment counts per image id

Tags: php, disqus

I'm trying to get the DISQUS comments and comment counts associated with a particular image ID for my PHP site.

**1) Get comment count:**

To get comment count, I've followed DISQUS' guide, but it just gives me a link to where the comments are on the comic... and not the total number... They say:

Append #disqus_thread to the href attribute in your links. This will tell Disqus which links to look up and return the comment count. For example:

```
<a href="http://foo.com/bar.html#disqus_thread">Link</a>.
```

But how would I get that count if my url string was like this:

```
<a href=".?action=viewimage&site=comics&id=66">Link</a>
```

So my questions are:

- Where would I append #disqus_thread?
- How can I get the comments count from that one comic URL and display those total comments on another page?
  Why does it just give me a link to the comments and not the comment number for that associated comic?

**2) Get specific comments, like most recent or most popular**

I haven't really found any documentation on this with the exception of this where they say I'd probably need to write my own script...

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The comment counting script will basically look up the thread and return the comment counts that match the URL - so it needs to be an absolute URL for that to work.

Assuming you were looking at [this document](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/565624), you'll also notice that there's an optional `data-disqus-identifier` attribute you can use, and you would use this in conjunction with a [disqus_identifier](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472099) in your commenting embed code. This will override the URL lookup and it will instead pull comment counts for the identifier. You will still need to append the `#disqus_thread` anchor to your URL, however.

For the second question, you would need to use the API to code a widget to display comments outside of the embed. There's a couple of different approaches you can take:

1. Load comments directly from the API using either the [posts/listPopular](http://disqus.com/api/docs/posts/listPopular/) or [posts/list](http://disqus.com/api/docs/posts/list/) endpoints (in conjunction with your `disqus_identifier`)
2. Load numerous threads details and use the RSS feed of the latest comments using the [threads/set](http://disqus.com/api/docs/threads/set/) endpoint. You can also use this to get the comment counts directly from the API rather than use the comment counting script.